# Vue component not updating when data changes without :key

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have this simple breadcrumbs component inside my app. There is a data property pickedTable but when it changes the component doesn't re-render. But when I add the :key="pickedTable" then it re-renders. Why is this happening?

Has anyone else experienced this issue?

[image]

```
export default {
    template: `
        <div class="cr-snackbar">
            <div class="cr-snackbar-selection">
                Table {{ pickedTable }}
            </div>
        </div>
    `,

    data()
    {
        return {
            pickedTable: '2',
        }
    },

    mounted()
    {
        setInterval(() => {
            this.pickedTable = '3'
        }, 3000)
    }
}
```

My solution was to add the key

```
<div class="cr-snackbar-selection" :key="pickedTable">
  Table {{ pickedTable }}
</div>
```

Comment: Does your minimal really reflect the issue? To me it looks fine - setter gets triggered - observer adds it to update hook - Dom should be updated an redrawn in next animation frame ?

Comment: @Estradiaz usually that is the case but for some reason it didn't redraw

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue but a feature.

> Vue uses an algorithm that minimizes element movement and tries to patch/reuse elements of the same type in-place as much as possible. With keys, it will reorder elements based on the order change of keys, and elements with keys that are no longer present will always be removed/destroyed.

Here is the official doc : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key

And here is a nice article on component re-rendering : https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/

Comment: When can we observe this issue in vue js?